# Why do some rows in gtsummary output show OR=1 and CI containing 1 but have significant p-values?

Tags: r

I am using `gtsummary` to create a table that merges univariate and multivariate regression results. Here's the code I'm using:

```
r2 <- tbl_regression(step.model, exponentiate = TRUE) %>% 
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>% 
  bold_labels() 

r1 <- dmtb11_v1 %>% tbl_uvregression(                         
  method = glm,                           
  y = status,                            
  method.args = list(family = binomial),  
  exponentiate = TRUE                     
)

tbl_merge(list(r2, r1))
```

[image]

The table is being generated successfully, but I noticed that some rows show an odds ratio (OR) of 1 with a confidence interval (CI) of 1.00-1.00, indicating significant p-values. However, an OR of 1 and a CI containing the value 1 should typically indicate non-significant p-values. Can someone explain this behavior?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Your question is a general question about regression modeling, not the gtsummary package. I suggest you close this post and post your question on Cross Validated. https://stats.stackexchange.com/